# How to add nested field after creating the ModelSerializer? Not in the class

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Basically i want to have fk_inventory as a nested field in StorageRackSerializer but as you guys can see I also need to use StorageRackSerializer in InventorySerializer.

How can i set the field after creating the serializer class?
I have tried creating a fk_inventory field and set it to None and tried to set to InventorySerializer  afterwards but didn't work.

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id    = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk_building     = models.OneToOneField(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, related_name='inventory')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.inventory_id}"

class StorageRack(models.Model):
    storage_rack_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    quantity        = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(50)])
    fk_inventory    = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="storage_racks")
    fk_product_id   = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="storage_racks")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.storage_rack_id}"

class StorageRackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_product_id = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)    
    fk_inventory = None    

    class Meta:
        model = StorageRack
        fields = ('storage_rack_id', 'quantity', 'fk_inventory', 'fk_product_id')
        

class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fk_building = StoreSerializer()
    storage_racks = StorageRackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('inventory_id', 'fk_building', 'storage_racks')
StorageRackSerializer.fk_inventory = InventorySerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field 'fk_inventory' in the validated data from SorageRackSerializer

```
validated_data = StorageRackSerializer(data=data)
validated_data['fk_inventory'] = InventorySerializer().data
```

Comment: How would I use this? Am I going to use it instead of StorageSerializer? I am also using ViewSets. I don't quite see how can I use this approach.

Comment: You can use custom response from ViewSet to return the validated_data.